# Showing header on screen with listview

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have a list of messages that I am showing using ListView.

Now, on top I need to show number of messages like : Inbox(5).

How should the layout look like?

Currently I am using linear layout having two text views for the 'sender' and the 'subject'. For every item in the list the same layout is used.

How can I write a layout where I specify the header and that should come only once at the top? It should not repeat with every list item.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your header (in the example below it's just a TextView) into your LinearLayout. Your listview will get **layout_height="0dp"** and **layout_weight="1"**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp">
    </TextView>
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/lv_messages" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I m not using list view.. I am using linear layout itself

Comment: <TextView
android:id="@+id/sender"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

android:text="TextView"

>
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/subject"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

android:text="TextView"
android:gravity="left"
>

</TextView>

Comment: it's your layout for listview items, but i give an example, how your activity layout should look like. Then you can have your header

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add header to your list view like this :

```
TextView tv=new TextView(this);

//Do your processing..and save your "Inbox(5)" message in tv

lv.addHeaderView(tv1);
```